# Как распределить массив по значениям?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть в такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
            [1] => Et non unde aut sed.
            [2] => Запись
            [3] => Не выполнено
            [4] => Sibyl Rogahn
            [5] => Prof.
            [6] => Физика
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
            [1] => Et in eum ullam.
            [2] => Не смотел
            [3] => Не выполнено
            [4] => Shana ****i
            [5] => Dr.
            [6] => География
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
            [1] => Quos ut laboriosam.
            [2] => Не смотел
            [3] => Не выполнено
            [4] => Elta Shanahan
            [5] => Ms.
            [6] => Физика
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
            [1] => Iusto at illum qui.
            [2] => И онлайн, и пересмотрел в записи
            [3] => 56
            [4] => Kristy Brakus
            [5] => Miss
            [6] => Математика
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
            [1] => Consequatur ut.
            [2] => Не смотел
            [3] => 86
            [4] => Willie Altenwerth
            [5] => Mrs.
            [6] => Физика
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
            [1] => Incidunt sint.
            [2] => Запись
            [3] => 50
            [4] => Gudrun Breitenberg
            [5] => Prof.
            [6] => География
        )

)
```

Как мне отсортировать этот массив по предметам(6 ключ массива), так, чтобы каждый из одинаковых предметов располагался под одинаковым ключом? Например: Чтобы массивы с индексом 0,2,4 (физика) были в под индексом 0, массивы под индексом 1,5(география) под индексом 1, а массив под индексом 3(математика) располагался в индексе 2. Два часа потратил, не получилось. Предметов может быть много, поэтому нужно, чтобы программа сама определяла какого индекса нет в новом массиве, который мы создаем, и добавляла его.

Конечный результат должен получится таким:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
                    [1] => Et non unde aut sed.
                    [2] => Запись
                    [3] => Не выполнено
                    [4] => Sibyl Rogahn
                    [5] => Prof.
                    [6] => Физика
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
                    [1] => Quos ut laboriosam.
                    [2] => Не смотел
                    [3] => Не выполнено
                    [4] => Elta Shanahan
                    [5] => Ms.
                    [6] => Физика
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
                    [1] => Consequatur ut.
                    [2] => Не смотел
                    [3] => 86
                    [4] => Willie Altenwerth
                    [5] => Mrs.
                    [6] => Физика
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
                    [1] => Et in eum ullam.
                    [2] => Не смотел
                    [3] => Не выполнено
                    [4] => Shana ****i
                    [5] => Dr.
                    [6] => География
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
                    [1] => Incidunt sint.
                    [2] => Запись
                    [3] => 50
                    [4] => Gudrun Breitenberg
                    [5] => Prof.
                    [6] => География
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => http://brown.com/vero-qui-ut-non-eos-neque-modi-iure
                    [1] => Iusto at illum qui.
                    [2] => И онлайн, и пересмотрел в записи
                    [3] => 56
                    [4] => Kristy Brakus
                    [5] => Miss
                    [6] => Математика
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: это не сортировка, а группировка. Циклом пройдитесь по массиву и соберите новый как вам нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если значением самого индекса тут не принципиально, то сначала просто возьмите уникальные значения предметов

```
$keys = array_unique(array_column($data, 6));
```

создайте новый массив где ключами будут предметы,  а значениями - пустой массив

```
$tmp = array_fill_keys($keys, []);
```

Далее пройдитесь по своему массиву и сложите данные в новый.

```
foreach($data as &$d){
    $key = $d[6];
    $tmp[$key][] = $d;
}
```

в конце сбросьте ключи

```
$result = array_values($tmp);
```